# Send Post Request to Server

Tags: java, android

i'm currently working in an app on android studio for the first time. I'm currently facing a problem and i don't know where to start ... I search for hours for documentation and all but i didn't find something that's working for me.

So my app is an app to order burgers. I fetch data from the server trought an API that i build (a simple php file to connect to the db an fetch the burger that i give to the app), then i make the view with the data that i fetch.

When i'm here, the user can chose the quantity that he want for his order and next he need to send his command to the server.
But i don't know how to do that part of the app. I try things that i found an internet but i never got a response from my server or anything. It's a little hard to work without seing anything.
Here is my app design :
[App View from user perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbn1L.png)

And here is my code :

1. Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
                downLoadJson("http://192.168.0.5/API/burger.php");
            }

            private void downLoadJson(final String urlWebService) {
                DownLoadJson getJson = new DownLoadJson(urlWebService, this);
                getJson.execute();
            }

        }
```

2. Here is my DownLoadJson Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DownLoadJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    final String urlWebService;
    final Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Burger> burgersList;

    public DownLoadJson(String url, Activity activity) {
        this.urlWebService = url;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"DOWNLOADING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            renderView(s);
            Button btnSend = activity.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("ENVOYER", ""+burgersList.toString());
                    new SendPostRequestToServer().execute("http://192.168.0.5/API/ServiceCommandes.php",burgersList.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            // Ouverture de la connexion avec l'api
            URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String json;
            while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(json + "\n");
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "WRONG URL");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Connection I/O error ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void renderView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        if (jsonObject.has("recette")) {
            burgersList = Burger.fromJson(jsonArray);
            BurgerAdapter adapter = new BurgerAdapter(activity, burgersList);
            ListView listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.addAll(burgersList);
            Log.d("DEBUG", "BURGER LIST = " + burgersList.size());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Burger> returnArrayList() {
        return burgersList;
    }
}
```

3. Here is my SendPostRequestToServer that i found an internet

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class SendPostRequestToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String data = "";

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            try {

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                    char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                    inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                    data += current;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("POST :", result); // this is expecting a response code to be sent from your server upon receiving the POST data
        }
    }
```

4. Php File:

```
<?php
// Headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
$PostData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if(!empty(($PostData)){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "DATA RECEIVE"));

}else{
    http_response_code(503);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "DATA ERROR"));
}

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fastfood");
// check erreur
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When i check the file_get_contents("php://input");
i get that : 
'''
2020-06-16 15:16:06.174 12488-12488/com.example.fastfood D/POST :: %5B%7B%22id%22%3A+%221%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Hamburger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%222%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Cheeseburger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%223%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Giant%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%224%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Giant+Max.%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%225%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Bacon+Max.%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%226%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Supreme+Cheese%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%227%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Supreme+Pepper%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%228%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Supreme+Chicken%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%229%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Fish+Burger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%2210%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Chicken+Burger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%2211%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Diabolo%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%2212%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Barbecue%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%5D

'''

I check on internet and when i decode that as a json i get :
[JSON DECODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKPDp.png)

Comment: Do you have an implemented code for the server which accepts POST request and process accordingly? Are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Comment: i have that error : 
' <br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp64\www\API\ServiceCommandes.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
    </table></font>'
I think it's because i send the all jsonArray in the param data

Comment: Whats the code in ServiceCommandes.php on line 7?

Comment: ''' $PostData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if(!empty(($PostData)){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "DATA RECEIVE"));

}else{
    http_response_code(503);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "DATA ERROR"));
}'''

Comment: When i do a echo file_get_contents("php://input")
My app logd write : 
2020-06-16 15:16:06.174 12488-12488/com.example.fastfood D/POST :: %5B%7B%22id%22%3A+%221%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Hamburger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%222%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Cheeseburger%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%223%22%2C%22nom%22%3A+%22Giant%22%2C%22quantite%22%3A+%220%22%7D%2C+%7B%22id%22%3A+%224%22%2C%22nom%22%3A (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had an error because i was sending an non Json array. 
In the method doinbackground i use urlEncode and when i checked what that fonction is doing i read :

> The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".

that's why when i json_decode the file_get_contents("php://input") i had a wrong jsonArray